# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

i am trying to create a unit test using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner but everytime i execute the test it says it cannot find SpringJUnit4ClassRunner using mvn install.

```
\src\test\java\com\jr\freedom\util\JsonParserUtilTest.java:11: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

here is my code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JsonParserUtilTest {

    private String jsonUser = "{ \"username\":\"jono111\",\"emailAddress\":\"jon@google.com\", \"password\":\"12345678\",\"firstName\":\"jono\", \"surname\":\"richy\", \"country\":\"united kingdom\",\"bio\":\"Bio stuff goes here about the user. where he comes from etc etc. all is well. lets go go go\" }";

    @Test
    public void testToJsonObject() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setBio("bio mate");
        user.setCountry("uk");
        user.setEmailAddress("jonney@hello.com");
        user.setFirstName("jono");
        user.setPassword("passwordfdsadsa");
        user.setUsername("crazy8");
        JSONObject jsonUser =  JsonPojo.toJsonObject(user);
        assertNotNull(jsonUser);
        assertNotNull(jsonUser.keys());
        System.out.println(jsonUser);

    }

    @Test
    public void testToObject(){
        JSONObject jsonUser = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonUser);
    }
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FreedomSpring</groupId>
    <artifactId>FreedomSpring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specifiy which directory within the project hierarchy will be considered 
                        as the root directory from the generated war file -->
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- Dependencies below for spring, hibernate, json etc -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

i am using springSource tool suit IDE to develop this spring mvc app and on the IDE it highlights SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as a error saying it cant be resolved despite me including all the necessary dependencies on my pom file.

Thanks

Comment: You should add test scope to your test dependencies, i.e. `junit`, `spring-test`, `mockito-all`, etc... I don't think that will solve your problem though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I downloaded your code and got it working locally, as long as I included the relevant import statements:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.Test;
...
```

Perhaps you're missing an import somewhere.

Comment: That did the trick. i always assumed eclipse will auto add imports for me!

Comment: I had to put the jar(spring-test-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar) file at the top of Build Path. You will find exact image of setting panel below.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, Add this in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this one by

- Deleting my local maven repo (~/.m2/repository) and
- In eclipse forcing a new build (Project->Clean...)

[Sourced from the appfuse forums](http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Maven-not-finding-junit-or-spring-dependencies-td3426778.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, open the termial and work the command below.
Do not forget to add the user in the place where the "user-name" is

```
cd /home/you-user/.m2/repository/
sudo rm -r junit
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to put spring-test jar at the "TOP" of Java Build Path
[image: Build Path figure]

Answer (score 1):

Go to pom.xml and make sure your file contain this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure that in this dependency is no "scope" node:

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you lost the package

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```